# Redshift - Split a table based on a column value

Tags: amazon-redshift

We have a daily redshift table with 500m records with these fields
timestamp, eventname, eventvalue.

We want a query that will take all the event with the name of 'X' and will put them in another redshift table.

If we do a simple `insert into...  select * where eventname=x`  then the performance is horrible (30 minutes run).

What's the best way to do it?

Comment: Is there an index on eventname

Comment: Do you have a DISTKEY and SORTKEY assigned to the original table and the destination table? Are they the same values for both tables? (That might help avoid copying data between nodes.) What proportion of the 500m records has a value of `X`? If you do a complete `INSERT INTO...SELECT *` (with no `WHERE`), does it run faster?

Answer (score 0):

You might see an increase in performance by loading data from the original table to S3 and copying from S3 to the new table.

Copy **to** S3 via `UNLOAD` (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_UNLOAD.html):

```
unload ('select * from t1 where eventname = x') to 's3://bucket/t' credentials '' gzip;
```

Copy **from** S3 via `COPY` (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_COPY.html):

```
copy t2 from 's3://bucket/t' credentials '' gzip;
```